# Is there a shorter way to write "x = not y" when y is a boolean without importing a module?

Tags: python

Just wondering if there is a smarter, shorter way to write this in python.

```
y = False
x = not y
```

In javascript I would:

```
y = false,
x = !y
```

Thanks!

Comment: Normally one wouldn't worry about 3 extra characters. What's the motivation for this question?

Comment: Python uses `not`. Don't fight the language to make it work like other langs or to save 2 characters.

Comment: Why wouldn't you say x = True?

Comment: I doubt there's a shorter way. I'm certain there's not a *better* way.

Comment: I suppose you could run your code through a preprocessor that replaces `!` with `not`, but then you're not writing Python anymore.  Just use `not`.

Comment: How about `x=1`  That's shorter than the Javascript version  ;^)

Comment: @mgilson, cute, but type puns are baaaad, m'kay? ;)

Comment: You can pay for the extra keystrokes out of your curly-brace budget.

Comment: Alright ya bunch'a yahoos! :)  I get it.  It's not that I'm trying to make über short code, I just didn't know if there was another operator out there in common use I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 8):

No, that's the shortest way (and you don't have to import any modules).

Comment: lies, my answer reveals a shorter way. not that it does exactly the same thing...

Comment: @Claudiu you can do `y=0;x=~y` as well, but that's not Pythonic (even though technically it's Python).

Comment: You can't, actually. `bool(~True)` is true (-2), and `bool(~False)` is still true (-1).

Comment: @Claudiu Wrong, the object type of 1-False is 'int' not 'bool' so it's not technically preserving Boolean object capabilities.

Comment: @Pyrce: Indeed, which is why I said "not that it does exactly the same thing..."

Comment: @Claudiu Fair enough, I didn't downvote or anything. I just didn't want there to be confusion on the point that they don't return the same type.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to save 3 characters?

WARNING: You should never do this. People will look at your code and do this

[image: facepalm]

You can do this:

```
y=0;x=1-y
```

You saved 6 characters on the `y` assignment and 4 on the `x` assignment! Hurrah! Also removed that pesky newline.

EDIT: Changed `y` for symmetry, and removed spaces because hey, we're reducing character count here, no? Also added cat.

Comment: This is also not very Pythonic, for what it's worth, and slightly unclear as y is not an integer type object. Though it is technically less characters to express.

Comment: @Pyrce, `isinstance(False,int)` will return True, so yes it is an integer type object. I must agree that it's not Pythonic, this is the sort of crap I'd expect to find in C.

Comment: yeah i will add the appropriate disclaimer

Comment: Wow, +1 for the cat addition!

Comment: Too bad the Django tag was removed, then we could have had ponies :-)

Comment: stackoverflow: where rep not only represents your knowledge of coding but also your knowledge of the internet zeitgeist. not that i am complaining =P.

Comment: These are important things to know if you're playing Python code golf.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python's built in Boolean object -- No, 'not y' is as simple as it gets. Python does not use the '!' operator except when doing a Boolean check (z != y => True or False object).

This is not a syntax burden to anyone who's used Python regularly (3 more characters than javascript/C).

Answer (score 1):

```
y=False
x=not y
```

This is not only shorter, but uglier too!

Comment: uglier indeed. what are we running a beauty parlor? less characters makes it run faster

Comment: @Claudiu: That's why I use single letters for ALL my variables, to increase execution speed :)

Answer (score 0):

Or this to save 1 character and not be ugly?

```
y = False
x = True
```